# SQL Server 2008 Mirroring

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, mirroring

How would one start the secondary mirror instance if the principal SQL server instance went off line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you don't have automatic failover and no witness, otherwise the mirror would have been promoted automatically.

In this case you need to switch the roles manually, with forced service:

```
ALTER DATABASE database_name SET PARTNER FORCE_SERVICE_DATA_LOSS
```

See [Role Switching During a Database Mirroring Session](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189850.aspx) 
and [ALTER DATABASE Database Mirroring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522476.aspx) for more detail.

Comment: Correct we don't have automatic fail over with a witness. Can you run that command on a database that is in a restoring state?

Comment: That's what it was made for.